# Validate contents of .ssh/known_hosts file

Tags: ssh, unknown-host, ssh-keygen, ssh-config

Is there some cli tool I can use to validate the contents of known_hosts? Maybe try to ping all the hosts in there and see if I can connect to each?

Probably using either `ssh-keygen` or `ssh-keyscan`?

Answer (score 5):

If you have list of all hosts available you can do it like this:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa -f hosts_list > ~/.ssh/known_hosts_revised
```

This will generate a new `known_hosts_revised` which you can make a `diff` with your current `know_hosts` to see the differences.

If you don't need to compare it you can simply do `... > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` to overwrite it (**WARNING:** the original `known_hosts` will be lost!)

The source of information are the OpenBSD man pages for [ssh-keyscan(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan).

**Edit**
The `hosts_list` expected in for:

```
1.2.3.4,1.2.4.4 name.my.domain,name,n.my.domain,n,1.2.3.4,1.2.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

At least for my setup, using `ssh-keyscan` is impossible due to my extensive `~/.ssh/config` file. I use lots of proxy commands, jump hosts, and alternate `Hostname` declarations.

For example:

```bash
# Connect to Tor nodes
Host *.onion
  ProxyCommand socat - SOCKS4A:localhost:%h:%p,socksport=9050

# Work jump box
Host bastion
  Hostname bastion.work.com

# Office system, e.g. bob.office -> bastion -> bob.work.com
Host *.office
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion nc -w600s $(echo "%h" |sed 's/\.office$/work.com/') %p

# Home system, e.g. adam -> home.com -> adam-laptop.local
Host adam
  Hostname adam-laptop.local
  ProxyJump home.com
```

None of the above will work.

Here's a script that should work for the rest though:

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

!/^#/ && NF > 2 {
  split($1, hosts, ",")
  key_type = $2
  gsub(/^ssh-/, "", key_type)
  gsub(/-.*/, "", key_type)
  for (h in hosts) {
    p = index(hosts[h], "]:")   # [host]:port (supports raw IPv6 hosts)
    if (!p && hosts[h] ~ /^[^:]+:[0-9]+$/) p = index(hosts[h], ":")  # host:port
    if (p > 0) {
      port = substr(hosts[h], p + 2)
      gsub("\[|\]?:" port, "", hosts[h])
    } else {
      port = 22
    }
    if (seen[key_type,port,hosts[h]]++) next  # prevent duplicate lookups
    if (port_list[key_type,port]) { comma = "," } else { comma = "" }
    port_list[key_type,port] = port_list[key_type,port] comma hosts[h]
  }
}
END {
  for (tp in port_list) {
    split(tp, a, SUBSEP)
    system("echo ssh-keyscan -t " a[1] " -p " a[2] " " port_list[tp])
  }
}
```

Remove the `echo` parts to run once you're convinced this will do what you desire.

This parses non-commented lines and with 3+ fields (since the format is `host_list key_type key_hash`). It splits the host list since it can be comma-delimited, and further parsing is needed because it can contain ports but `ssh-keyscan` cannot accept hosts in the format used by `known_hosts`.

There are two ways a port can be specified:

1. The old style, which does not work with bare IPv6 addresses, is `host:port`
2. The new style, which is required for bare IPv6 addresses, is `[host]:port`

`p` is set to the position of `]:` if present (the new style). If that string isn't present, we check for the old style and reset `p`.

If `p` is positive, we have a port specification. Extract the port and remove (it and the square brackets) from the host name. Otherwise, the port is 22.

Just in case there are duplicate entries, we check for them and continue if we've already seen the type,port,host combination (`x++` is false (0) only when first run). Finally, we push the host to a comma-delimited list string in the `port_list` array as keyed by a tuple of type and port.

After reading in the entire known_hosts file, we iterate on the `type,port` tuple pairs that key the `port_list` array, split them into an array named `a`, and run `ssh-keyscan` on them.

Run this like `awk -f 'this_script.awk' ~/.ssh/known_hosts` and if you like the `ssh-keyscan` commands that it spits out, remove the `echo` from the system command and re-run.

**Do not pipe this output into `~/.ssh/known_hosts`!** You will want to manually review the results (and probably filter out the comments). Also, you can't redirect output onto one of the files used in the input.